# How to change method not marked with @Test (mean it is not into current test class), but marked by my annotation

Tags: java, testng, listener

The project has the test `Test_FindYNetNewsViaGoogle.java`

```
public class Test_FindYNetNewsViaGoogle extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void testGoToYNNHomeUrl(){
        app.google().goToGoogleHome();
        app.google().search("class_name");
        app.google().enterSite(webElement2);
        assertThat(app.browser().whatSiteIsOpened(), equalTo("urlYNetNews"));
    }
}
```

A test scenario includes performance of app.google().search("www.ynetnews.com") that is located in GoogleHelper.class

```
public class GoogleHelper extends HelperBase{

    private final String googleHomeUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

    public GoogleHelper(WebDriver wd) {super(wd);}
   
    public void goToGoogleHome() {
        String curUrl = wd.getCurrentUrl();

        if (googleHomeUrl.equals(curUrl)) {return;}
        wd.navigate().to(googleHomeUrl);
    }

    @StaleElementAnnotation(retries = 2, seconds = 1)
    public void search(String search) {
        WebElement we_search = wd.findElemnt(By.className(search));
        click(we_search);      
    }

    public void click(WebElement search) {
        // was refresh page
        throw new StaleElementReferenceException("test exception");
    }

    public void enterSite(WebElement url){
            click(url.locator));
    }

}
```

I special write throw the StaleElementReferenceException exception, in order to image that after the previous step there were refresh of page.

So, to resolve this I need to change search(String) to

```
public void search(String search) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < DEFAULT_RETRIES) {
        try {
            ++count;
            return searchService(search);
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void searchService(String search) {
    WebElement we_search = wd.findElemnt(By.className(search));
    click(we_search);      
}
```

This okay if you have few those methods. But if there are many of it. So I think that there is solve in which we can invoke some Listener that can call in this case our initial method by surrounded it with as above written.

I have not found any TestNg listeners can give only test method name where was throw the exception. In my case it is Test_FindYNetNewsViaGoogle.testGoToYNNHomeUrl() and not GoogleHelper.click(WebElement search).

Please assist me!

Comment: why have you added `reflection` as the tag?

Comment: by reflection I want to send reties and timeout values

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a static method to retry the required methods. Maybe you can add this to your `GoogleHelper` class.

```java
public static void retry(Runnable method, int maxTries, long seconds) throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < maxTries) {
        try {
            ++count;
            method.run();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could use the above method in your test.

```java
public class Test_FindYNetNewsViaGoogle extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void testGoToYNNHomeUrl(){
        app.google().goToGoogleHome();
        GoogleHelper.retry(() -> app.google().search("class_name"), 2 , 1);
        app.google().enterSite(webElement2);
        assertThat(app.browser().whatSiteIsOpened(), equalTo("urlYNetNews"));
    }
}
```

Comment: that gets the same result : the String testName = result.getName() returns "testGoToYNNHomeUrl" but not "search".  Because the method "search" is located into business logic class and not test class.

Comment: @MaximS Okay, so you want only the search method to be retried instead of the full test ?

Comment: @MaximS Also, is `StaleElementReferenceException` a runtime exception. From the code I assume it is a runtime exception rather than a compile time exception

Comment: sorry for my late. Yes, you are right - I want only the search method to be retried instead of the full test

Comment: @MaximS does the updated answer solve your question

Comment: Thanks for your full support. I think this is what I need. Now there is no time to check it, because my manager asked me to solve another, more priority problem. I'll get my full answer back in a week.